# gtag appears in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, google-ads-api

I was making some changes to a Wordpress page, I have access to the CPanel. I didn't realize until the next day that this text appeared above the site header: "gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXXXXXX'); "

[show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BRIG.png)

From what I've researched, it's the global site tag for conversion tracking in Google Ads, but I don't know how to hide it or why it appeared.

Does anyone know how to hide it and where it is located? Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the Google Tag Manager script and should be within script tags `<script> gtag function goes here </script>`. Perhaps you have accidentally deleted part of this. You can refer to this resource https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/install to see how tag manager should be included in the head of the website.

This script could be included anywhere, but it's likely to be in the header.php in your theme, or if you have a plugin installed called header and footer (or similar plugin that enables you to add js to the head) it could be found in the admin page for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just solved it, I did a review of my plugins one by one until I found the cause, it's a plugin called Tracking Code Manager, I just deactivated it. Greetings